# laravel sorting arrays last 5 unique and reverse

Tags: php, laravel

I have an **array** of **id's** and I want to filter those **id's** to last 5 and **unique ids**.

```
$recently_viewed_ids 

    array:16 [▼
      0 => 1
      1 => 2
      2 => 1
      3 => 2
      4 => 8
      5 => 7
      6 => 6
      7 => 6
      8 => 6
      9 => 5
      10 => 8
      11 => 4
      12 => 1
      13 => 1
      14 => 1
      15 => 1
    ]
```

---

Here is my code and it's messing up because I'm getting 85672

```
$items = array_slice(array_unique(array_reverse($recently_viewed_ids)), -5);
```

---

Output I am expecting

```
14856
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use next combination of array functions:

```
array_slice( // get first 5 values
    array_unique( // get only unique values
       array_reverse($arr) //reverse array for get last values
    )
,0,5);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel, I believe you can rewrite the correct answer to:

```php
return collect($arr)
    ->reverse()
    ->unique()
    ->slice(0, 5)
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$items = array_slice(array_unique(array_reverse($recently_viewed_ids)), 5);
```